# Combination of multiple regex in just one

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having trouble extracting a certain string from a file ... in case the input string will be:

```
Codigo: 000001
Cliente: 000030 John Red

Codigo: 000002
Cliente: 000032 Kin Ahaul paulo
```

My expected Result is:

```
Codigo: 000001 - John Red
Codigo: 000002 - Kin Ahaul Paulo
```

My result is:

```
Codigo: 000001 -
Codigo: 000002 -
```

Regex:

```
(Codigo: [0-9]{6})
```

What do I need to do and create a regex for each one? In case, to extract the code one regex and to extract the other name?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: How are you reading the file? You may do that with no regex just when reading the file line by line if it has the same structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use three regular expressions. One that will extract the `Codigo` lines, and one that will extract the `Cliente` lines. Then you can loop through the data and append the `Cliente` data after cleaning with a third.

Extract Codigo:

```
/Codigo:\s\d*/g
```

Extract Cliente line:

```
/Cliente:.*/g
```

Clean Cliente line by removing the match of this:

```
/Cliente:\s\d*/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single regex using capturing groups:

```
(Codigo: \d+)\nCliente: \d+ (.*)
```

The desired result would be `$1 - $2` using the first and second groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex, the words **Codigo:** and **Cliente:** must be present, then you should make sure a space, a number(digits) and a name are present in order:

```
(Codigo:[ ]+\d+|Cliente:[ ]+\d+)([A-Za-z ]+)
```

Comment: You will ave to process the matches to add "-", regex can only find the required matches for you, but you will have to process these matches, i adjusted the regex to give you exactly two groups, you will have to concatenate them using "-"